# C# BackgroundWorker Exiting Unexpectedly

Tags: c#, session, citrix

I have thef ollowing background worker in my app which is meant to start a user's session automatically if there is not already one available.

This is done on a backgroundworker (backgroundInit) on initialisation. As you can see below, I have a `while` loop which continues to run as long as the var `checker` remains false:

```
var checker = false;
var i = 0;
while (checker == false)
{
   _session = funcs.GetSession(_servers, _name);
   _sessID = _session[0].Trim();
   _servName = _session[1];

   checker = funcs.CheckRunning("lync.exe");
   i++;

   if (i > 200)
   {
      break;
   }
}
```

The CheckRunning method just checks if a specified program (in this case, "lync") is currently running and returns either `true` or `false` accordingly (This is done via a CMD command).

When I run the app in an empty session however, the while loop only iterates one time before breaking out, even though "Lync" is definitely not running.

Is there any reason why running a process or too many processes from within a Backgroundworker may cause it to exit?

Comment: So `checker` is `false` after `checker = funcs.CheckRunning("lync.exe");` ? If so, this question makes no sense, since the `BackgroundWorker` is exiting **expectedly**, and the problem is the function that checks your process. Otherwise, you need to be more explicit, is there any exception thrown? Have you tried step-by-step debugging?

Comment: May be some exception thrown? E.g. your `GetSession` returns null or empty array.

Comment: while(!funcs.CheckRunning("lync.exe")) would be simpler to read. And rename to IsRunning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments mentioned, this was not an issue with the `BackgroundWorker`, but rather an exception occurring at `_sessID = session[0].Trim();` where the session had not yet started, so there is no ID.

To resolve this, I simply placed a `Try/Catch` block around this assignment, and let the program silently ignore the exception:

```
    try
    {
        _sessID = _session[0].Trim();
        _servName = _session[1];
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        // MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
    }
```

This works for me, as the loop will continue checking until the counter `i` reaches the 200 limit, at which stage the program will accept failure.

Comment: This is not the ideal solution, but it will do for now. Eventually all this code will need to be refactored.